# How to Set Permissions

Tags: java, ms-access-2007

I'm working on login and register interfaces.

when User registered as an administrator and login as admin it should take me to a screen specified for admins only !

and when User registered as employee and login as employee it should take me to a screen that employees use only !

```
public class Register extends JFrame {


public Register() {
    initComponents();
    setTitle("Register");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

}



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    TF1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    TF2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    TF3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    TF4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    B1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    PF1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    RB1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    RB2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("First Name");

    jLabel2.setText("Last Name");

    jLabel3.setText("Username");

    jLabel4.setText("Password");

    jLabel5.setText("Email");

    B1.setText("Register");
    B1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            B1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    RB1.setText("Manager");

    RB2.setText("Employee");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                    .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(TF4)
                        .addComponent(PF1))
                    .addGap(51, 51, 51))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                            .addComponent(TF3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 270, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(TF2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 270, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(TF1))))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(RB1)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(RB2)
                    .addGap(161, 319, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(166, 166, 166)
            .addComponent(B1)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(23, 23, 23)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(TF1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(TF2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(TF3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(TF4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(PF1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(RB1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(RB2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 4, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(B1)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void B1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    Connection con = null;
try {
  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver") ;
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Tickets");


  Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); //Query statment

  stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Register VALUES ('"+TF1.getText()+"','"+TF2.getText()+"','"+TF3.getText()+"','"+TF4.getText()+"','"+PF1.getText()+"')");


  setVisible(false);


  } catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
}
}                                  


public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Register().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just do `if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("employee")){ //code to make visible employee page }else{ // make visible login page}`

Comment: but i don't know what's gonna the user type ! 
i mean it's all saved in a database 
and to know if he's employee or admin depends on how he registered 

by clicking after the register thing on a radio button for an employee or admin ?

Comment: Ya but when you store the user, you must saving the user type too in you database. Then just select the userType from your database and check what kind of user he/she is.